# "Going up" instead of "put up"

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

> The posters are **going up** all over the town.

Is "going up" used more commonly in this context?

Or is this one more likely to be said:

> The poster are being **put up** all over the town.

So which one is used more?(in both BrE and AmE.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer must be an opinion.

Comment: Both are used, no-one can say which is used more.

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=posters%20going%20up%2C%20posters%20put%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) suggests "posters put up" is slightly more common

[image]

However, as with any Ngram search, you have to treat the results with some skepticism.  "Going up" and "put up" imply different things, and so a direct comparison is more or less useless.  It all depends on what you want to say.

Comment: Ngram searches books; they are only indirectly indicative of speech usage, especially the informal kind.